# How to implement touch and hold for sprite kit?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

I recently started working with `sprite-kit`. I know `touchesBegan` works for just one tap but is there something i can use that will recognize a touch being held down?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to implement something like shooting then you need to start shooting in `touchesBegan` method and stop shooting in `touchesEnded` method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self startShooting];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self stopShooting];
}
```

For other purposes you can add [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to the `SKScene`

Comment: Thanks Andrey, one more thing. The game I'm working on has you tap the screen to make a character move up, with gravity having it come back down. Eventually there will be objects coming in from the side in which you have to try to avoid. Now when i tap the screen, my character does what i want it to do, which is move up 200 points, but if i tap again before it goes back to the bottom, it doesn't go up another 200 because it seems gravity has already kicked in. Is there a way to reset the gravity effecting the character as soon as the screen has been tapped?

Comment: I can't understand you, can you post your code? Create another question for that

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can use a boolean with the update method:

```
bool isTouching = false;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    isTouching = true;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    isTouching = false;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if(isTouching){
        //shooting! 
    }
}
```

You can easily combine method's of yours inside the isTouching block if you prefer, and use touchesBegan to lets say aim the bullets at the same time.

You don't need to worry about timers as the update method will keep executing the code block  as long as isTouching == true

Answer (score 3):

```
var isTouching = false

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    handleTouches(touches) 
    isTouching = true;
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    handleTouches(touches)
    isTouching = false;
}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    if isTouching{
        //Shoot CODE!
    }
}
```